# Unable to partition hard drive with Yosemite (Disk Utility hangs)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, ssd, partition

I have a 2007 model Macbook Pro running Yosemite 10.10.1. My father recently upgraded my hard drive for me from the stock 320GB hdd to a hybrid 500GB hdd. He's not really a Mac user and said there were some kind of issues partitioning the hard drive so right now I have 320GB of available space with 180GB of unallocated space.

I've read there are some issues with Yosemite and partitioning hard drives. I've tried expanding my partition but each time Disk Utility just ends up freezing. Should I just reinstall Yosemite entirely or what are my options? I'm at "A" school in the Navy right now and don't have access to an external drive of any kind, although I MAY be able to get my hands on one.

Here's the output of diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:         Microsoft Reserved                         134.2 MB   disk0s1
2:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s2
3:                  Apple_HFS  Macintosh HD           319.2 GB   disk0s3
4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s4
```

And here is the next:

```
 diskutil cs list
 No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

Output of sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0:

```
 gpt show: disk0: mediasize=500107862016; sectorsize=512; blocks=976773168
 gpt show: disk0: PMBR at sector 0
 gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
 gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 976773167
  start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34     262144      1  GPT part - E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE
   262178       2014         
   264192     409600      2  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   673792  623464448      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
624138240    1269760      4  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
625408000  351365135         
976773135         32         Sec GPT table
976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Please start Terminal.app, enter 'diskutil list' and 'diskutil cs list' (each followed by 'enter'-key) and add the output to your question.

Comment: @klanomath see above!

Comment: The partition layout is non-standard: "#1 Microsoft reserved disk0s1" is really uncommon. Please add 'sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0' and enter an admin password (the password won't be visible typing it!). Please also add the hard disk model.

Comment: @klanomath add aboved! I appreciate your time btw.

Comment: did you already install some apps and stored some personal data on the disk or is it a fresh install? Do you have a backup and a thumb drive?

Comment: There is personal data on the disk but nothing that can't be easily replicated. I do not have a thumb drive at this time. Doesn't Yosemite have a way to reinstall itself from WiFi or something?